# Spray sbt-resolver not working for Akka http app

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, akka-http

I used this plugin https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver

Looks like according to the doc, I only need to add `addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.8.0")`

And start the app using `sbt re-start`

Then the console display `... killing ...`

I have no idea what's going on, do I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

`re-start` is meant to be used from the `sbt` console. If you run the command from the shell, `sbt` will run `re-start`, the command will finish (with your process in the background), and `sbt` will then immediately exit.

Start up the console, then run `re-start`:

```
$ sbt
...
[info] Set current project to my-app
> re-start
[info] Application my-app not yet started
[info] Starting application my-app in the background ...
>
```